# MVC calling views from other virtual directories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create a 'shared' MVC application, which can be used for all common data that is used by other MVC and legacy Web applications.

For example, I have two Virtual Directories setup on my server:

```
mysite.com/Report 
mysite.com/Base
```

So what I'd like to be able to do is this to include a view from the 'base' folder in the 'Report' one;

```
@Html.Partial("/Base/Views/Shared/_NavigateMenu.cshtml")
```

Note that ~ in Report will go to mysite.com/Report, I cant use that.

However doing so results in the following exception:

```
The virtual path '/Base/Views/Shared/_NavigateMenu.cshtml' maps to another application, which is not allowed.
```

I know about areas however there are a lot of downsides in using them, firstly I cant (or is very difficult) to migrate the existing legacy applications into a area, also logistically it is nicer to have each MVC application separated and have a space for common objects. (Not just views, but css, images, etc.)

So the question is how do I 'allow' MVC to map and thus access to other applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to share a MVC aplication is basically trying to share several different components :

- Controllers should be shared through a separate class library, reachable through area registrations
- Models can be in any referenced class library

for views, I assume base `Base` application root folder contains the application web.config. `Views`, hosting the views, can contain a web.config relative to views rendering (say for razor configuration)

To use `Views` in application Report, you have to create a virtual directory `SharedViews` (or whatever name you want) in `Report`, which will point to the physical path of `Base`/`Views`.

Then you will be able to write :

```
@Html.Partial("~/SharedViews/Shared/_NavigateMenu.cshtml")
```

The points are :

- having a virtual directory in `Report`, to avoid switching from an app to another
- having this virtual directory not reference the root directory of `Base`, to avoid app configuration conflicts

Comment: Many thanks. Aye, I'm just looking to add views for things like a constant navigation menu, one place for the jquery et al, etc. So what your saying is the only way to do it is to add a virtual directory within IIS to make it appear that 'base' is within the 'report' application?

Comment: Thanks again! I added a virtual directory and it works. Bit of a hack really, which is unfortunate. Areas just don't give a clean separation of different functions like different projects in virtual directories. Seems like a rather large weak spot in the MVC framework.

Comment: @BJury as for static assets, they do not need to be in a shared virtual directory. But keep in mind they will be delivered with the configuration of the app which host them (encoding, compression, cache, etc) Also, if you are looking for higher level redistributable mvc parts, you may have a look at "portable areas"

Answer (score 1):

you can resolve this problem using the char `~` before virtual path i.e.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Base/Views/Shared/_NavigateMenu.cshtml")
```

or else

if it is specified path set up as a Virtual Directory in IIS than it may treat it as another application even though it's in the same directory as the main application.

Comment: But the base is in a different Virtual Directory, ~ would be the home path of results. , Eg mysite.com/Results/, so it needs to get mysite.com/base/views...